# Probability Discrete Math

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
What is the probability that the sum of any of these three numbers is odd?
I know that I should use $ n \choose k $ somehow and I know that my professor used this as his equation: $\frac{{ 5 \choose 3}  + {5 \choose 1}*{ 4 \choose 2}}{{9\choose3}}$ [3 odds or 1 odd/2 evens] but I don't understand why.  And I couldn't get the \frac to work for LaTeX haha I tried many different ways including taking the dollar signs out and only around the entire equation, but I still couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Three numbers can be choosen out of 9 in ${9 \choose 3}$ possible ways.  The sum will be odd if the three numbers are choosen either from $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ which can be done in ${5 \choose 3}$ ways or one number is choosen from  $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ - ${5 \choose 1}$ ways and 2 numbers are choosen from $\{2,4,6,8\}$ which can be done in ${ 4 \choose 2}$ ways. 
So the cases when the sum is odd are ${5 \choose 3} + {5 \choose 1} \times { 4 \choose 2}$.